# What's the preferred way on math.SE of typesetting differential operators in an integral?

Tags: support, mathjax

Say for example $$\int \frac{1}{x} \textrm{d}x$$

Comment: Isn't there a meta on this already?

Comment: Bill. Read that other relatively recent thread (from last October), where this was discussed. You are, of course, welcome to add something to that discussion. I closed this as a duplicate in order to keep all the arguments and opinions in one place.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jyrki.